# How to create a numeric vector with correlation = 0.25?

Tags: r

Is easy to find the correlation with R with `cor()` function but how to do the opposite way? How to create two numeric vector with correlation = 0.25?

Comment: `cor()` doesn't work on a single vector - it expects either a matrix, or two vectors

Answer (score 2):

This code is copypasted completely from the [Elements of Statistical Modeling for Experimental Biology](https://www.middleprofessor.com/files/applied-biostatistics_bookdown/_book/creating-fake-data.html):

```
n <- 10^3
z <- rnorm(n)       # the common cause, with sigma = 1
rho <- 0.25         # the true correlation between X1 and X2
beta_z <- sqrt(rho) # the easiest way to get effects of z on X1 and X2 that generates rho
sigma_x <- sqrt(1 - rho) # we will make the variance of X1 and X2 = 1, so the "explained" variance in X is beta_z^2 = rho so this is the sqrt of the unexplained variance
x1 <- beta_z*z + rnorm(n, sd=sigma_x)
x2 <- beta_z*z + rnorm(n, sd=sigma_x)
cor(x1,x2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to sample from a 2-D multivariate Normal with the following co-variance matrix:

```
[1.00 0.25]
[0.25 1.00]
```

The two vectors are then given by the corresponding columns in the resulting matrix:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm( 1000, c(0,0), matrix(c(1,0.25,0.25,1),2,2) )
cor( A[,1], A[,2] )
# [1] 0.2496565
```